# How are drush and jenkins used together for continuous integration?

Tags: drush, deployment

I hear the buzz words, "continuous integration", "drush" and "jenkins" often. Thus, sparking my interest.

How are drush and jenkins used together for continuous integration?

Also, why would you want to use drush and jenkins together?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For my projects, I use a build script made of Drush commands in a Jenkins job. I use my [Phing Drush Task](http://drupal.org/project/phingdrushtask) project to run Drush from a [Phing](http://www.phing.info/) build script. This allow me to leverage the existing Phing tasks (eg. files copy, phplint, etc.). With the help of Drush, this build script

- Downloads all non-custom code (ie. Drupal core and contribs module and themes) with [Drush Make](http://drupal.org/project/drush_make) to `./dist`
- Expands placeholders in a versioned `settings.php` (ie. replace `${db_host}` with the actual DB hostname) while copying it to the freshly downloaded `./dist/sites/default` folder.
- Copy custom modules and themes to `./dist/sites/all/modules/custom` and `./dist/sites/all/themes/custom`
- Run `phplint` for all files from my custom modules and themes.
- Copy everything under `./dist` to a pre-configured webroot.
- Run `drush site-install testing` and `drush pm-enable simpletest` to install a fresh site using the build code base and able to run SimpleTest.
- Run `drush test-run` to run my custom module test suites.
- Run `drush coder-review`.

Here is a commented [build.xml template](http://reload.github.com/phing-drupal-template/) for Drush usage in Jenkins.

Comment: Does that mean your CI environement is on the same machine than your php server ? I don't understand how you manage to copy your own sources in sites/all/modules/custom (for instance). This is probably because I don't know how work drush ... but nowhere I see equivalent of scp / ftp task from your CI Plateform to Php one.

Comment: Yes the CI server and the webserver serving the test site are on the same machine. Off course you could also copy the file from the CI workspace to the webserver host. The rsync command of Drush could be used for this. Then Drush can be used to run command on the machine hosting the webserver.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Phing in Jenkins, so you can use Drush through http://drupal.org/project/phingdrushtask (Pierre Buyle on SE.COM)

Custom example:

```
 <drush command='cc' root="${project.drupal.core.dir}" uri="${env.host.name}" assume="yes">
  <param>all</param>
</drush>
```